# Get all time using timestamp in php

Tags: php, join, timestamp

I have two tables (shops,booking), In shop table i saved my shop open time and close time ( 09:00am to 09:00pm) in timestamp,In booking table I saved shop booking time,I can get shop booked time with help of an SQL `JOIN`.

I want to get the available time and booked time with a gap of 30 minutes  after shop open time.

**Example**

```
09:00am - 09:30am avl
09:30am - 10:00am avl
10:00am - 10:40am booked
10:40am - 11:00am  av
```

I just want to get availiable time with booked time.How can i do this ?

Shop table

```
id      shop_open_time      shop_close_time
1       1545296406          1545339606
```

Booking table

```
id      user_id     service_start_time      service_booking_time
1       1           1545300006              1545302406
```

Comment: Can you show us what you already tried?

Comment: Add example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @ino : i just want a list where i can see shop availiable and booked time , thats it

Comment: Check this post, It might help you with something.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536146/display-hours-in-half-hour-range?rq=1][1]