# PHP Display Hour range today and tomorrow

Tags: php

I've got the tutorial from [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536146/display-hours-in-half-hour-range)

The PHP code:

```
$start = '20:00:00';
$end = '07:59:59'; //need to show until tomorrow time.
$time = strtotime($start);
$timeStop = strtotime($end);

while($time<$timeStop) {
    echo date('H:i', $time);
    $time = strtotime('+30 minutes', $time);
    echo ' - ' . date('H:i', $time) . '<br/>';
}
```

Now I need to show the time from `20:00:00` until tomorrow at `07:59:59`.

Current code when I'm trying to run it got no result (empty).

Comment: You are likely getting no result because 20:00:00 is greater than 07:59:59, so `$time<$timeStop` is `false`.

Comment: In other words, your code has no concept of date—just time.

Comment: Just add a date to your times and it will work :)

Comment: Just to clarify your question—you are trying to echo the half hour intervals between these two dates, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it's just comparing the times not dates so obviously in your example the start time is greater than the end time.
Try the following example it works perfectly.

```php
<?php

$TodayDate = date("Y-m-d");

$start = $TodayDate.' 20:00:00';

$TomorrowDate = new DateTime('tomorrow');

$TomorrowDate = $TomorrowDate->format('Y-m-d');

$end = $TomorrowDate.' 07:59:59'; //need to show until tomorrow time.
$time = strtotime($start);
$timeStop = strtotime($end);

while($time<$timeStop) {
    echo date('H:i', $time);
    $time = strtotime('+30 minutes', $time);
    echo ' - ' . date('H:i', $time) . '<br/>';
}
?>
```

```text
20:00 - 20:30
20:30 - 21:00
21:00 - 21:30
21:30 - 22:00
22:00 - 22:30
22:30 - 23:00
23:00 - 23:30
23:30 - 00:00
00:00 - 00:30
00:30 - 01:00
01:00 - 01:30
01:30 - 02:00
02:00 - 02:30
02:30 - 03:00
03:00 - 03:30
03:30 - 04:00
04:00 - 04:30
04:30 - 05:00
05:00 - 05:30
05:30 - 06:00
06:00 - 06:30
06:30 - 07:00
07:00 - 07:30
07:30 - 08:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `DateTime` class with it's associated methods - `add` ~ this would perhaps simplify the task? It is simple to modify the above to work with a pre-defined start time / end time

```
$now = new DateTime();
$end = new DateTime( date( DATE_ATOM, strtotime( 'now + 1day' ) ) );

while( $now->add( new DateInterval('PT30M') ) < $end ){
    echo $now->format( 'H:i:s' ) . '<br />';
}
```

To use the actual desired start/end times

```
$start = date( DATE_ATOM, strtotime( 'today 8pm' ) );
$finish = date( DATE_ATOM, strtotime( sprintf( '%s + 1day',$start ) ) );

$now = new DateTime( $start);
$end = new DateTime( $finish );

while( $now->add( new DateInterval('PT30M') ) < $end ){
    echo $now->format( 'H:i:s' ) . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: What if you need a specific start and end time?

Answer (score 1):

Just add some date.
Search for 08:00:00 of which day?

```
$start = '01/01/2019 20:00:00';
$end = '01/02/2019 08:00:00';

$time = strtotime($start);
$timeStop = strtotime($end);

while ($time<$timeStop) {
    echo date('H:i', $time);
    $time = strtotime('+30 minutes', $time);
    echo ' - ' . date('H:i', $time) . '<br/>';
}
```